# No module named PIL.Image

Tags: python, django

I just add django-simple-captcha into my apache2.2+django1.8 project

in python command line

```
from PIL.Image import *
```

didn't show any error

and I have already set all the files in Python2.7/site-packages to chmod 777

but when I start server and request some page

there will be error logs:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=16530): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/root/code/python/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py'., 
Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__, 
response = self.get_response(request), referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_response, 
response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info()), referer: 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 264, in 
if resolver.urlconf_module is None:, referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 396, in urlconf_module, 
self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name), referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
File "/usr/local/python27/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module, referer: 
__import__(name), referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
File "/root/code/python/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 38, in <module>, referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),, referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 33, in include, referer: 
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module), referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
File "/usr/local/python27/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module, referer: 
__import__(name), referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/captcha/urls.py", line 6, in <module>, referer: 
from captcha import views, referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/captcha/views.py", line 21, in <module>, referer: 
import Image, referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Image.py", line 1, in <module>, referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
from PIL.Image import *, referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
ImportError: No module named PIL.Image, referer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
```

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add manually **PIL** library source in your **root path** of project.

Download source here http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/#pil117 and copy `PIL` directory to your project.

Answer (score 0):

PIL is not  imported as PIL, you just need to import Image directly

```
import Image
```

or

```
from Image import *
```